# SharePoint: You don't have permission to view the data in this list

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I administer our Power BI offering.  A user came to me with this problem:

While viewing a list in SharePoint:
Microsoft Lists
Integrate
Power BI
Visualize the list

After clicking on "Visualize the list" he gets the message,

> Something went wrong. You don't have permission to view the data in this list. Please reach out to the owners of the list to get access.

Given that message, can I safely assume this is not really a problem for me as the Power BI administrator?

He is the owner of the list.  He has "Full Control" permission.  What else would he need?

One piece of information that may be important:  We're using Microsoft's government cloud for Power BI (app.powerbigov.us) and maybe other apps.  For example, we're using sharepoint.com, but I'm told it's GCC.  But we may be using some features from the commercial cloud.

**Update #1:  Random permissions**

After nothing changing, the user can now generate the Power BI report.  When he clicks "publish" it reports success, but the report is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Users need to have at least Read permission on SharePoint lists that they want to access wherever they access them, via PowerBi or SharePoint UI or other.

If the user has been the owner of the list, he should be able to access the content. Please double-check his permissions on the list and also check if he could access the content successfully via SharePoint UI.

[image]

Comment: Did that.  As I stated, he has "Full Control" permission.  Yes, he has access to the content in SharePoint.  He manages said content.  He's the primary contributor.

Comment: As he could access the content in SharePoint successfully, this issue should be about PowerBI, maybe there are some wrong settings on your PowerBi. Microsoft has a dedicated PowerBI community, you can try to ask for help there. https://community.powerbi.com/